# CSS Sidebar Background Color Full Width

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, sidebar

Hi I’m developing a site: [HERE](http://emergination.co.uk/)

My sidebar background color seems to be not getting in full width ,it has weird margin at right part. I have tried to manage by increase the size and move left by adjusting the padding at the left but the right side seems to be at is even if making the size of the background to 100% or 200%.

`

```
.sidebar .widgettitle { 
margin-left: -50px; !important; 
background:#606060;
padding:10px 0px 10px 25px;
text-transform:uppercase !important;
width: 210%;
max-width: 210%;
background-size: 210% auto !important;
height: auto;
```

}
`

Comment: Share some piece of code

Comment: Thanks code I sue was ` .sidebar .widgettitle { 
margin-left: -50px; !important; 
background:#606060;
padding:10px 0px 10px 25px;
text-transform:uppercase !important;

} `

Answer (score 0):

It seems that css class container has a padding on both left and right at the value of 50 pixels. You can overwrite this in your own CSS file.

[pic showing .container style in grid.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzGnL.png)

Comment: Thanks my code was:

` .sidebar .widgettitle { 
margin-left: -50px; !important; 
background:#606060;
padding:10px 0px 10px 25px;
text-transform:uppercase !important;

}`

But shows the same result

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Anmol Nandha is correct - it is caused by the `.container` element having `padding-left` and `padding-right` of `50px`.

You could remove the specific styling in your grid.css, or if you don't want to edit framework files, you might consider adding a `id` attribute on the `.container` element, and cancel out the effects by setting `padding-left` and `padding-right` to 0.

Note that if you do that, then the contents in the left (main) part will stick to the edge. You might want to add `padding-left: 50px` on the `.entry-content-wrapper` to compensate for it.

Of course there is the option to tweak the CSS of your sidebar instead, but I have outlined the easiest way (in my opinion) to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Gagas I've tried to remove and add padding to .entry-content-wrapper it seems that when i remove the padding from container it removes every padding including header and footer area.

Comment: Then you could use my latter suggestion - give `id` to the parent element of the sidebar, and remove the padding using that id.